# epplus c# цена деления на графике

Tags: c#, epplus

Всем доброго времени суток.  Создаю Excel файл с помощью epplus добаляю в него  линейный (eChartType.Line) график (ExcelChart)  в источнике миллиардные значения а на графике цену деления нужно сделать миллиарды. Все что я понял это делается через свойства оси Y (YAxis)

Comment: Две секунды расшифровывал "цену деления". Здравствуй, профдеформация! >_>

Answer (score 1):

```
ExcelChart ec = (ExcelLineChart)ws.Drawings.AddChart("chart_1", eChartType.Line);
ec.YAxis.DisplayUnit = 1000000; //цена деления (миллионы)
```